# Repeat control should be updated after update backend Document

Tags: xpages

Currently I am using the AutoRotator of Dojo, to display a set of content documents. I populate this caroussel with a repeat control, who gets his data collection from a managed bean. There is a method who collect the universal ids from a view and put it in a HashMap as a bean property.

In the repeat control, there is a panel with a datasources binded to it. The datasource is document, and the documentId is from the data collection out of the managed bean.
I decided this way, because the body is Mime entity with lots of formatted information

So far so good, everything works fine......
When a content document, via another XPage is updated and saved, the documents in the caroussel will not been updated.

Does anyone knows a way to update my data collection? Is it possible to update the data collection Hashmap in the Managed Bean and will the repeatcontrol get the new data?
Or are there other ways to stay in sync between back en front end.

Comment: Some sample code to highlight your problem would help. Once a AutoRotator is populated it runs offline isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the bean into the applicationContext, so it will be accessible by all users of the database. Then instead of only collecting the docids, collect the actual mime entries (important: Don't use NotesMimeEntry classes, use a standard Java object in the bean). You could use a map with the unid as key and the HTML as content. Then in the querySave you update the applicationBean.

makes sense?

Comment: As I understand you, make a Managed Bean in the ApplicationContext who will make for every Backend document an Java object, and the body(mime) and bind this collection of Java Objects to the repeat control. And in the Query Save update the corresponding Java Object.

Comment: Correct. Just make sure you don't store any Notes class in your object